# How to select any row that has a number in columns x-y that is between 0 and 12?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In access, I'm trying to query my database to return any row that has a value between 0 and 12 in any of 6 columns. How can I do this?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result would helpful.

Comment: You should share your table schema to help us provide an answer.

Comment: Usually a sign of a broken data model - all data of the same "type" (such that you want to write queries that deal with all stored values of that "type" in a uniform manner) should be stored in *one* column (with as many rows as are necessary to represent the number of values to be stored and often with an additional column to hold the *data* that is currently embedded in those column *names*, mixing data and metadata)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col1 between 0 and 12 or
      t.col2 between 0 and 12 or
      t.col3 between 0 and 12 or
      t.col4 between 0 and 12 or
      t.col5 between 0 and 12 or
      t.col6 between 0 and 12 ;
```

The need to do this type of query suggests a poor data model.  Having columns that are distinguished only by a number suggests that you really need a separate table with one row for each of the columns.

Comment: I eventually figured it out, and your point about this being a poor data model is valid. I'll try and use your solution to try and improve our table. Thank you!